# Are there infinitely many triplets of primes giving this concatenation in base ten?

Tags: number-theory

Let be $p$, $q$ and $r$ primes, with $p<q<r$.

I search for primes $p$, $q$ and $r$ such that:

$p\cdot q\cdot r$ is the concatenation in base ten of $(2\cdot q)$ and $q$.

The example I give is:

$p=3$
$q=43$
$r=67$

where $3\cdot 43\cdot 67=8643$ is the concatenation in base ten of $86$ and $43$.

Can you prove that there are infinitely many primes $p$ $q$ and $r$ with this property?

Comment: So we need to identify infinitely many primes that are one more than six times a repunit?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $q$ has $n$ digits. Then the concatenation of $2q$ and $q$ is equivalent to multiplying $q$ by $2\cdot10^n+1$, which is always divisible by $3$, so $p=3$ and $r=\frac{2\cdot10^n+1}3$.

So there will be infinitely many triples $(p,q,r)$ if and only if there are infinitely many [primes of the form $\frac{2\cdot10^n+1}3$](https://oeis.org/A093170), which is an impossible proposition.